# Density of LPG in g/L

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, combustion, density

What is the density of LPG (in vapour state) in g/L?
Please note that I'm asking about the density of vapour LPG when it comes out of the cylinder. NOT the liquefied density!

Answer (score 1):

LPG – propane – gas density is 1.55 times heavier than air. It is  **$1.898$ g/L** vs  $ 1.225$ g/L for air (both 15°C at sea level).

For more details, please visit this [website](http://www.elgas.com.au/blog/453-the-science-a-properties-of-lpg).